# Master Detail CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-awesome

Recently come across a Master Detail CRUD Demo using Grid and PopupForm by [aspnetawesome.com](http://aspnetawesome.com/). I downloaded the demo because it was exactly what i was looking for but when i try to run it i keep getting the error

> Error 4   Assembly 'Omu.AwesomeMvc, Version=4.7.3.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9c6fbba722ea1caf' uses 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\AwesomeMvcDemo\AwesomeMvcDemo\bin\Omu.AwesomeMvc.dll

thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the demo is using mvc 5 version of the library, and is referencing  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.2" in packages.config, the nuget packages get pulled when you first build (see readme.txt), for some reason you are referencing the Aspnet.mvc version 3

in case you need to use the library on a different version of mvc you can
download the library,  trial version http://aspnetawesome.com/Download/MvcTrial, it has separate dlls for mvc 3, 4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

It might be using heigher version MVC, pls try with updating MVC package either nuget or manually